# MySQL previous value

Tags: mysql, consistency

I have some problems with MySQL. I have a table where every row looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|index  |sum    |change |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Now I need to figure out how to calculate the sum. The sum is

sum(current) = sum(previous) + change(current).

```
 +-------+----------------------------+----------+
 |index  |sum                         |change    |
 +-------+----------------------------+----------+
 |0      |sum(0)                      |0         | //Beginning values are set
 +-------+----------------------------+----------+
 |1      |sum(1) = sum(0) + change(1) |change(1) | //change is the only thing that changes the sum
 +-------+----------------------------+----------+
 |2      |sum(2) = sum(1) + change(2) |change(2) |
 +-------+----------------------------+----------+
                    ......
```

My problems are:

1. I don't know how to define sum(current) = sum(previous) + change(current).
2. How can I keep the data consistent if I delete or update for example index(1)? I don't know how to do this, since every value depends on its predecessor.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do this using variables:

```
select t.index, (@s := @s + change) as sum, change
from t cross join
     (select @s := 0) params
order by index;
```

Note that names such as `index` and `sum` are reserved words and/or keywords.  You should be using different names for your query.

If you want to keep the results consistent when the data changes, then you have three options:

- Use a trigger.
- Run an `update` query in your application to recalculate the values.
- Just do the calculation when you fetch the data.  Then the results are always consistent with the data.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!